Difference between anti-equivalence of categories and duality
How is an anti-equivalence of categories defined? I have read that it is an equivalence between two categories $C$ and $D$ with contravariant functors $F : C \to D$ and $G : D \to C$ instead of covariant functors, but it seems not right, because then we need to compose covariant functors $F : C^{op} \to D$ and $G : D^{op} \to C$ which cannot really be.
Is it the same thing than a duality then, i.e. an equivalence between $C^{op}$ and $D$ ?

Similar to: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21744/what-is-an-antiequivalence-of-two-categories. Also, please tell us where you saw that term used.

I've seen that, but I didn't mind because it does not seem to be on the same platform as here. Here's where they mention 'anti-equivalence' : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89quivalence_de_cat%C3%A9gories.

Given $F : C^\mathrm{op} \to D$ and $G : D^\mathrm{op} \to C$ you have $G^\mathrm{op} \circ F : C^\mathrm{op} \to C^\mathrm{op}$ and $F \circ G^\mathrm{op} : D \to D$ (and of course dualising gives you an equivalence between $C$ and $D^\mathrm{op}$).

So it's the same thing as a duality !

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

I rephrase : so it's the same thing as a duality ?

(my comment was addressing the answers by Naim)

No problem ! But it may not be an answer, that's what I was stressing.

I don't know what you mean by "duality", but an anti-equivalence as defined in that Wikipédia page is just an equivalence between $C$ and $D^\mathrm{op}$ (or $C^\mathrm{op}$ and $D$). There is no anti-equivalence between $C$ and $C$ in general because the identity $C \to C$ is not a contravariant functor.
